# Efficient way to gathering data by datetime range for multiple rows stored in another table in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, django-views

I've got two models:

```py
class CombinedData(models.Model):
    datetimestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    N1_leq = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    N2_leq = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)


class DateTimeFolderTable(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    datetimestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    device = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

`CombinedData` example:

| datetimestamp | N1_leq | N2_leq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-14 12:20:00 | 52.3 | 54.2 |
| 2023-04-14 12:30:00 | 51.2 | 52.7 |
| 2023-04-14 12:40:00 | 45.7 | 47.3 |
| 2023-04-14 12:50:00 | 43.9 | 45.3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-04-14 13:20:00 | 53.1 | 52.1 |

`DateTimeFolderTable` example:

| Path | datetimestamp | device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| file1 | 2023-04-14 12:00:00 | 1 |
| file2 | 2023-04-14 12:05:00 | 1 |
| file3 | 2023-04-14 12:52:00 | 1 |
| file4 | 2023-04-14 13:20:00 | 1 |
| file5 | 2023-04-14 14:10:00 | 1 |
| file6 | 2023-04-14 11:45:00 | 2 |
| file7 | 2023-04-14 12:13:00 | 2 |
| file8 | 2023-04-14 12:45:00 | 2 |
| file9 | 2023-04-14 13:28:00 | 2 |
| file10 | 2023-04-14 13:41:00 | 2 |

`CombinedData` contains information in evenly-spaced time intervals. `DateTimeFolderTable` contains `path` to some files, but its in not-evenly spaced and random intervals.

I want to render a table, where for each object of `Combined Data` ther is a list of all files in `DateTime FolderTable` that have `datetimestamp` in some range (ie. from a full hour to next full hour).

This is expected table i want to render:

| datetimestamp | N1_leq | N2_leq | paths_device_1 | paths_device_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-14 12:20:00 | 52.3 | 54.2 | file1, file2, file3 | file7, file8 |
| 2023-04-14 12:30:00 | 51.2 | 52.7 | file1, file2, file3 | file7, file8 |
| 2023-04-14 12:40:00 | 45.7 | 47.3 | file1, file2, file3 | file7, file8 |
| 2023-04-14 12:50:00 | 43.9 | 45.3 | file1, file2, file3 | file7, file8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-04-14 13:20:00 | 53.1 | 52.1 | file4 | file9, file10 |

I come with this solution:

In `views.py` i have:

```py
def miner(request):
    combineddata = CombinedData.objects.all()
   
    folders1 = []
    folders2 = []

    for singledatarow in combineddata:
        datetimeofdata = getattr(singledatarow, 'datetimestamp')
        startdatetime = datetimeofdata.replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0)
        enddatetime = datetimeofdata + datetime.timedelta(minutes=59)
        folders1.append(DateTimeFolderTable.objects.filter(datetimestamp__gte=startdatetime, datetimestamp__lte = enddatetime, device=1))
        folders1.append(DateTimeFolderTable.objects.filter(datetimestamp__gte=startdatetime, datetimestamp__lte = enddatetime, device=2))
        
    
    combineddatafolders = zip(combineddata,folders1,folders2)

    context = {"combineddata":combineddata,"combineddatafolders":combineddatafolders}

    return render(request, 'app/miner.html', context)
```

and then in `app/miner.html`:

```html
<table>
    <thead class="table-dark">
        <tr>
            <th> datetimestamp </th>
            <th> N1_leq </th>
            <th> N2_leq </th>
            <th> DOWNLOAD1 </th>
            <th> DOWNLOAD2 </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    {% for datarow,folder1,folder2 in combineddatafolders %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ datarow.datetimestamp|date:"Y-m-d H:i" }} </td>
            <td> {{ datarow.N1_leq }} </td>
            <td> {{ datarow.N2_leq }} </td>
            <td> 
                {% for singlefolder in folder1 %}    
                    {{singlefolder.path}}
                {% endfor %}        
            </td>
                        <td> 
                {% for singlefolder in folder2 %}    
                    {{singlefolder.path}}
                {% endfor %}        
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    
</table>
```

Which works as expected. But I feel that iterate over whole `CombinedData` dataset in `views.py` and filtering `DateTimeFolderTable` dataset for every single row of `CombinedData` isn't the most efficiant (and pythonic) way to achieve what I want.

I thought about some kind of many-to-many relation ship in models, or another way to assign the `DateTimeFolderTable` data, but didn't come up with any idea. I have the impression that the solution is trivially simple and I just don't see something.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CombinedData(models.Model):
    datetimestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    N1_leq = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    N2_leq = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.datetimestamp)#'{}'.format(self.datetimestamp.strftime('%H'))

class DateTimeFolderTable(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    datetimestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    device = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    mtm = models.ManyToManyField(CombinedData, blank=True)
```

The `secondary` DateTimeFolderTable model has each mtm field associated with each datetimestamp field of the `primary` CombinedData model that corresponds to its `hour`. You can link them in another way (I linked the fields manually through the admin panel).

To access the fields of a secondary model, use the model `name` prefixed with [`_set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects). See 'Following relationships backward' for details.

The loop takes `'path'` into a list and concatenates it into a string. I have commented out three lines that print out all the data of the primary and secondary models, you can uncomment them and print them out.

```
combineddata = CombinedData.objects.all().prefetch_related('datetimefoldertable_set')

    folders1 = []
    folders2 = []
    for i in combineddata:
        """
        print(i.datetimestamp, i.N1_leq, i.N2_leq,
              ",".join(i.datetimefoldertable_set.all().filter(device = 1).values_list('path', flat=True)),
              ",".join(i.datetimefoldertable_set.all().filter(device = 2).values_list('path', flat=True)))
        """
        folders1.append(",".join(i.datetimefoldertable_set.all().filter(device=1).values_list('path', flat=True)))
        folders2.append(",".join(i.datetimefoldertable_set.all().filter(device=2).values_list('path', flat=True)))

    combineddatafolders = zip(combineddata, folders1, folders2)
```